# how to read the correct Hexadecimal data when the data send are big than 0x80

Tags: java, hex

now I am a socket server,and I need to read the Hexadecimal data from the client.
when the client send the data like this : 0x55 0x56 0x57,I can read the correct data 
but when the client send the data like this : 0x80 0x81 0x82, The data I read are wrong like this 63 63 63.The code I read the data is

```
try
    {
        if((b = (byte) mBufferedReaderClient.read())!= -1)
        {
            y=0xFF&b;
            System.out.println(y);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read to the `int` variable:

```
try
{
    int b;
    if((b = mBufferedReaderClient.read())!= -1)
    {
        y=0xFF&b;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Currently you cast to `byte` first. The `byte` type can hold only numbers from `-128` to `127`, thus you're already losing the information here. For example, if `255` will be received, it will be automatically converted to `-1` and you will incorrectly interpret it as the end of the stream.

Comment: I used your code ,but the data are wrong,  too.it print out 253 253 253.I guess that if I read the correct data.